# WPF Storyboard Animation. Cannot databind to SeekStoryboard Offset. Need ideas

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have created a DataTemplate that is used for ListBoxItems.  I have created a color animation where the item's background color starts out as green and slowly turns red over a period of time.

The problem is this -- I need to set the Storyboard Seek Offset depending on a timestamp that is contained within the ListBox's item (example: an item suddenly populates the ListBox whose color animation should be moved, say, 17 seconds into the animation).  When I initially created this I thought this would be quite easy as I would simply bind Offset to a value converter that returned a TimeSpan value based off of the binding item's timestamp.  But, as I discovered, you cannot perform databinding to a SeekStoryboard Offset.

Can anyone suggest a workaround or perhaps some code-behind magic that can take care of this?  This Listbox will contain very few items (maybe 5 at the most), so iterating through the collection and programmatically grabbing the Storyboard resource and manually setting the offset would not be too time consuming. However, I am not sure how to do this since my Listbox is populated by custom objects and not a UIElement of type ListBoxItem.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TicketTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Lime"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:15:0" Value="Yellow"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:30:0" Value="Orange"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:45:0" Value="Red"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="1" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Padding="5,1">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="GhostWhite"  Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="GhostWhite"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Grid>
                <!-- ELEMENTS FOR LISTBOXITEM TEMPLATE -->
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded" SourceName="border">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="WarningStory" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnLoaded1}"/>
                <SeekStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="WarningStory" Offset="0" <!-- cannot databind to Offset =( --> Origin="BeginTime" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround to enable binding to a property that is not a dependency property. It requires that the class that owns the target property is derived from `DependencyObject`, which is fortunately true for `SeekStoryboard`.

You would create an [attached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) helper property with a [`PropertyChangedCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) that sets the actual target property.

```
public static class SeekStoryboardExt
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BindableOffset", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(SeekStoryboardExt),
            new PropertyMetadata(BindableOffsetPropertyChanged));

    public static TimeSpan GetBindableOffset(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (TimeSpan)obj.GetValue(BindableOffsetProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindableOffset(DependencyObject obj, TimeSpan value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindableOffsetProperty, value);
    }

    private static void BindableOffsetPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var seekStoryboard = obj as SeekStoryboard;
        if (seekStoryboard != null)
        {
            seekStoryboard.Offset = (TimeSpan)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

You would now bind the helper property instead of the target property:

```
<SeekStoryboard local:SeekStoryboardExt.BindableOffset="{Binding ...}" .../>
```